# Drupal 6 - Permissions issue after migration

Tags: drupal, database-migration

My Database was quite large with lots of test data in tables like watchdog, access log,etc.. and I was running in to some trouble uploading. Then I proceeded to dive into the database and started truncating tables willy-nilly. I am figuring out that I should have used a little more discretion because I have had issues on the new production server.

The main problem is that annonymous users can't view any content, even though in 'permissions', they are set to access content. Also, they were definitely able to view content before the migration, so it had to be one of the tables I hacked. Because everything else is running smoothly.

Anyone have an idea which table, if truncated, might produce symptoms like this?

**Update:** - I checked that I have user 0 - which would probably yielded the same symptoms. - Problem persists though..

Comment: Do you mean they can't view any content?

Comment: Yes, basically they get an "Access Denied" on all content types like page, blog, etc.. In permissions, everything is good -

Comment: cinqoTimo: you might want to edit that typo in your post to avoid confusion then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried rebuilding permissions?

http://yourdomain.com/?q=admin/content/node-settings/rebuild

Or running update.php? Either should rebuild the node access table.

Answer (score 0):

Do your `users` table contain a row with `uid=0`? If not, create it. This row represents anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `(0,0,'all',1,0,0)` in your node_access table?

See this comment:  http://drupal.org/node/122476#comment-1058731